# URL query param sub delimiter handling

Tags: node.js, parsing, url

I am trying to deal with a url string 
`http://localhost:8000/lastnames/location/city/215722?filter=beginswith:p&paging=(offset:2,limit:2)`

How do I handle parsing out those sub objects? The `(offset:2,limit:2)` just gets parsed out as a string. These are accepted delimiters in the URL spec so I thought something like `url.parse` (in node) would handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "URL specification" (actually, ["Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax, RFC-3986"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines the syntax of the `query` component to be:

```
query = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

In other words, `sub-delims` (which include parentheses) and colons really are just ordinary characters in a query.

If requested (by passing `true` as its second argument), `url.parse` will also split the query into key-value assignments using the sub-delims `=` and `&`, as per the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. Other sub-delims are not involved in query string encoding.

Note that `url.parse` doesn't decode pct-encoded sequences such as `%25`; for that, you need `decodeURIComponent`. That should be done only after the components are fully broken down into their parts.

In short, if you want to parse `(offset:2,limit:2)` into some other structured object, you'll need to do that yourself, possibly by using regexes or -- if the format is complicated enough -- a parser generator like jison. In any event, you should leave the percent-decoding step until the very end; otherwise, percent-encoded sub-delims won't be parsed correctly.

Comment: This answers the question, that I have to make a parser for that structure and that url.parse just reads it as a string between the next param.